# Why isn't my try/catch block catching System.AggregateException?

Tags: c#, exception, aggregateexception

I have some code that makes an asynchronous http call like so:

```
try
{
  var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
  var uri = "http://myendpoint.com";

  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine("an error occurred");
}
```

Most of the time this works fine, but occasionally I'll get a `System.AggregateException` which reads `One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. --- End of inner exception stack trace`

My catch statement is never reached in the case above, and I'm not sure why.  I know that Tasks have some complicating factors when they throw exceptions but what I don't know is how to go about handling them in my catch statement?

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Shouldn't you await an async request?

Comment: @jkj2000: You're probably seeing that exception from another task, not the one returned from `GetAsync` in the code above. The sample code you posted will always catch the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is not thrown in the same thread of your try/catch. That's why your catch block is not executed.

Check [this article about `HttpClient`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client):

```
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();    // Throw if not a success code.

    // ...
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    // Handle exception.
}
```

Comment: I think that should be `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`.  Looks like you copied that typo in from the article.

Comment: I didn't realize. Thanks @juharr!

Comment: Thanks.  I inherited the code above, which has been out there for a while, and wondered if we needed to do a Task.WaitAll in there.  Unfortunately we're on .Net 4.0 so async and await aren't available to us, and the needed fixes to get them on there just aren't going to happen on this system.